# EACCES permission error with firebase cli even after installing node with nvm

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-tools

I looked at another post that said these issues were quite common and followed the link there (https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally).  I did what it recommended there and installed node via nvm.  The error still happens.  Exact error is below.

After running firebase login:

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/home/.config/configstore/firebase-tools.json'
You don't have access to this file.

```
at Object.openSync (fs.js:476:3)
at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:377:35)
at Configstore.get all [as all] (/Users/home/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/configstore/index.js:34:25)
at Configstore.get (/Users/home/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/configstore/index.js:77:27)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/home/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/previews.js:11:30)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19) {
```

errno: -13,
syscall: 'open',
code: 'EACCES',
path: '/Users/home/.config/configstore/firebase-tools.json'
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by changing the owner of the config store via chown:

```
sudo chown -R username /Users/username/.config
```